# Unable to display FCM notification using 'node fcm-notification'

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a video calling app where a user gets notified via a notification when there is an incoming call and be able to click on the notification to start the call. Right now, the notification gets pushed when the app is closed or is running in the background, but doesn't when the app is opened in foreground.

Also, clicking on the notification when the app is in background or not running will only open the app and not start the video call. The only way I can start the call is by receiving a notification when the app is in background / not running, manually opening the application and then clicking on the notification.

Here is my code that handles the notification sending:

```
var fcm = require('fcm-notification');
var serverKey = require('./fcmKey.json');
var FCM = new fcm(serverKey);

const payloadBody = {
     room,
     caller,
     language,
     receiver
}

var message = {
     token : deviceToken,
     data : payloadBody,
     notificaton: {
         title : 'MyApp',
         body: 'Somebody is calling'
}

FCM.send(message, function(err, response) {
    if(err) {
        console.error('Notification error: ${JSON.stringify(err)}');
    } else {
        console.error('Notification success: ${JSON.stringify(response)}');
    }
}
```

My manifest also contains the fcm service like this:

```
<service android:name="com.evollu.react.fcm.MessagingService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing with respect to foreground and background behavior is exactly [how notification type messages are supposed to work](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notification-messages-with-optional-data-payload).  If you want to take control over the behavior of the notification that gets displayed to the user, you should remove the notification payload from the message, and build the whole thing yourself in response to the [data payload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages).  You'll [receive that message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) in a FirebaseMessagingService subclass that you create.